# Domain of a composite function

Tags: functions

Consider the built-in function `FunctionDomain` to find a domain of a composite function f(f(x)) where f(x)=1/x.

```
f[x_]:=1/x
FunctionDomain[Composition[f, f][x], x]
FunctionDomain[1/(1/x), x]
```

The output is `True` in both cases.

Apparently Mathematica simplifies the argument before applying the `FunctionDomain`. That's why it gives mathematically incorrect output (x=0 should be excluded). `Composition[f,f][x]`=f(f(x)) = 1/(1/x)= x. And the domain of x is all real numbers.
In case when `Hold` function is applied to `1/(1/x)` the output is x < 0 || x > 0 as it should be.

```
FunctionDomain[Hold[1/(1/x)], x]
```

Output: `x < 0 || x > 0`

But when `Hold` is applied to `Composition[f, f][x]` The result is completely different. `FunctionDomain[Hold[Composition[f, f][x]], x]` returns the input as output.

Why doesn't it work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

One idea is to convert the `Composition` into a form that partially evaluates its arguments, something like:

```
freezeComposition[c_Composition] := Composition[
    Apply@Hold,
    ReplaceRepeated[#, Hold[x_]->x]&,
    Apply@Defer,
    Composition[Hold,Evaluate,#]&/@c
]
```

Then, we can do:

```
f[x_]:=1/x
FunctionDomain[freezeComposition[Composition[f,f]][x], x]
```

> x<0||x>0

Comment: @ CarlWoll the function that you have defined works perfectly! However I'm not able to understand the syntax as I am a beginner user of Mathematica.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve the same result using any of built-in Hold functions?
I noticed that not only `FunctionDomain` but functions like `Reduce` and `ReplaceAll` return mathematically incorrect results.
`f[x_] := 1/x; {Reduce[1/(1/x) == 0, x, Reals],Reduce[f[f[x]] == 0, x, Reals],Solve[1/(1/x) == 0, x, Reals],Solve[1/(1/x) == 0, x, Reals],FunctionDomain[1/(1/x), x],FunctionDomain[f[f[x]], x],1/(1/x) /. x -> 0,f[f[x]] /. x -> 0}`
How can I prevent (partial) evaluation of the first argument?

Comment: @roman465. All of these simplifications occur because *Mathematica* always attempts to find a *general* solution to the problem while (sort of) ignoring special (or corner) cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `StrictFunctionDomain` function from [`` Domains` `` package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139329/14303) which evaluates given expression in special environment that prevents removal of removable singularities:

```
f // ClearAll
f[x_] := 1/x

StrictFunctionDomain[Composition[f, f][x], x]
(* x < 0 || x > 0 *)
StrictFunctionDomain[1/(1/x), x]
(* x < 0 || x > 0 *)
StrictFunctionDomain[Hold[1/(1/x)], x]
(* x < 0 || x > 0 *)
```