# How does FunctionDomain work?

Tags: functions, implementation-details

`FunctionDomain[(x^2-x-2)/(x^2+x-6),x]`

gives

> `x < -3 || -3 < x < 2 || x > 2`.

However, when I factor the numerator and denominator the result is different:

`FunctionDomain[((x - 2) (x + 1))/((x - 2) (x + 3)),x]`

> `x < -3 || x > -3`

As I understand things, *Mathematica* first of all simplifies the argument and then applies the function. But both expressions simplify to 
`(x + 1)/(x + 3)`.

Why is the output different?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Evaluate `((x - 2) (x + 1))/((x - 2) (x + 3))` and see what it gives.  It *automatically* simplifies to `(1 + x)/(3 + x)`. The second input you show is effectively

```
FunctionDomain[(1 + x)/(3 + x), x]
```

The different results you get are not due to `FunctionDomain`, but due to the different inputs which are passed to it.

You may wonder if the fully automatic simplification of this fraction should be considered incorrect. There is a closely related discussion here, where I argued that such simplifications are in fact more useful than harmful and quite reasonable:

- [A one line proof that one is zero using Mathematica 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65624/12)

---

**Update**

Per @ChipHurst's comment, wrapping the argument in `Hold` works too:

```
FunctionDomain[Hold[((x - 2) (x + 1))/((x - 2) (x + 3))], x]
(* x < -3 || -3 < x < 2 || x > 2 *)
```

This appears to be an undocumented extension of `FunctionDomain`.  Only `Hold` works, not other function with the `HoldAll` attribute (not even `HoldForm`).

Comment: FWIW adding `Hold` seems to work `In[1]:= FunctionDomain[Hold[((x - 2) (x + 1))/((x - 2) (x + 3))],x]

Out[1]= x<-3||-3<x<2||x>2`

Comment: @ChipHurst That was completely unexpected to me. So this is an undocumented extension then?

Comment: No idea, just tried it and it worked.

Comment: @Szabolcs Apparently the assertion that `Simplify` is applied to the expression before `FunctionDomain` operates is false as the two expressions supplied in the question simplify to `(1+x)/(3+x)`

Comment: @JackLaVigne No, `Simplify` is not applied.  `((x - 2) (x + 1))/((x - 2) (x + 3))` *evaluates directly* to `(1 + x)/(3 + x)`, without `Simplify`. `FunctionExpand` never even sees the expression the OP entered, only the expression that it evaluated to.

Comment: @Szabolcs Got it. The expression fed to `FunctionDomain` follows the normal evaluation procedure in Mathematica. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: `FunctionDomain[Hold[expr_]]` is the intended use - primarily for use in WolframAlpha. If you type [function domain x/x](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=function+domain+x%2Fx) into WolframAlpha, for example, you'll get $x\neq0$.

Answer (score 9):

In *Mathematica* trivial removable singularities of like `x/x` (in full form `Times[x, Power[x, -1]]`) are replaced by `1` during ordinary evaluation of `Times`, when appropriate pair of positive and negative `Power` of same expression is encountered. Similarly `1/(1/x)` is replaced by `x` during evaluation of `Power`.

To prevent both kinds of replacements, during evaluation, we can dynamically assign dummy head to `Power[...]` expressions, using `Block`. Then we can wrap resulting expression with `Hold`, replace dummy head back with `Power`, and pass it to `FunctionDomain`:

```
f // ClearAll
f[x_] := 1/x
Block[{Power = power}, x f[x]] (* x power[x, -1] *)
Hold@Evaluate@% /. power -> Power (* Hold[x/x] *)
FunctionDomain[%, x] (* x<0 || x>0 *)
```

This technique evaluates expression, just without removing singularities. In contrast simple passing of expression to `FunctionDomain` either evaluates expression completely, removing singularities:

```
FunctionDomain[x f[x], x] (* True *)
```

or completely prevents evaluation, including evaluation of functions we would like to evaluate:

```
FunctionDomain[Hold[x f[x]], x]
(* ... FunctionDomain:Unable to find the domain with the available methods. *)
(* FunctionDomain[Hold[x f[x]],x] *)
```

---

## Package

Function automating above `Block`ed evaluation is implemented in following package:

```
BeginPackage@"Domains`"; Unprotect@"`*"; ClearAll@"`*"

StrictFunctionDomain::usage = "\
StrictFunctionDomain[expr, vars, dom] \
finds the largest domain of definition of expression expr, treated as function \
in given variables vars, with arguments and values in domain dom, \
excludes all singularities encountered while evaluating expr, \
even if those singularities would be removed \
during ordinary evaluation of expr. \
vars can be a symbol or list of symbols. Domain dom can be Reals or Complexes.\

StrictFunctionDomain[expr, vars] \
uses Reals as domain.\

StrictFunctionDomain[expr] or StrictFunctionDomain[expr, Automatic, ...] \
uses variables extracted from expr.";

RestrictDomain::usage = "\
RestrictDomain[expr, vars, dom] \
returns expr with sub-expressions subExpr, for which, \
domain can be restricted, replaced with ConditionalExpression[subExpr, cond] \
where cond are conditions restricting domain of subExpr, \
treated as function in given variables vars, \
with arguments and values in domain dom. \
vars can be a symbol or list of symbols. Domain dom can be Reals or Complexes.\

RestrictDomain[expr, vars] \
uses Reals as domain.\

RestrictDomain[expr] or RestrictDomain[expr, Automatic, ...] \
for each replaced sub-expression uses variables extracted from it.";

Begin@"`Private`"; ClearAll@"`*"

StrictFunctionDomain // Attributes = HoldFirst;
StrictFunctionDomain[
    expr_, vars_ : Automatic, dom : Reals | Complexes : Reals,
    opts : OptionsPattern@FunctionDomain
] :=
    With[{eval = evaluateKeepingSingularities@expr},
        FunctionDomain @@ Unevaluated /@ Join[
            eval,
            getHeldVars[vars]@eval,
            HoldComplete[dom, opts]
        ]
    ]

RestrictDomain // Attributes = HoldFirst;
RestrictDomain[
    expr_, vars_ : Automatic, dom : Reals | Complexes : Reals,
    opts : OptionsPattern@FunctionDomain
] :=
    ReleaseHold@With[{getHeldVars = getHeldVars@vars},
        evaluateKeepingSingularities@expr /.
            subExpr : (acceptableHeads@dom)[___] :>
                ConditionalExpression[subExpr,
                    FunctionDomain @@ Unevaluated /@ Join[
                        HoldComplete@subExpr,
                        getHeldVars@subExpr,
                        HoldComplete[dom, opts]
                    ]
                ]
    ]

evaluateKeepingSingularities = Function[,
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{Power},
        With[{protected = Unprotect@Power},
            Power@args__ /; Not@VectorQ[{args}, NumericQ] := power@args;
            Protect@protected
        ];
        HoldComplete@#&@# /. power -> Power
    ],
    HoldAllComplete
];

getHeldVars // Attributes = HoldAllComplete;
getHeldVars@Automatic = Function[,
    (HoldComplete[#]&@Union@Cases[Unevaluated@#,
        s_Symbol /; Not@MemberQ[Attributes@s, Constant] :> HoldComplete@s,
        {-1}
    ])[[All, All, 1]],
    HoldAllComplete
];
getHeldVars@vars_ := Function[, HoldComplete@vars, HoldAllComplete]

acceptableHeads@Complexes =
    Abs | AiryAi | AiryAiPrime | AiryBi | AiryBiPrime | AngerJ | ArcCos |
    ArcCosh | ArcCot | ArcCoth | ArcCsc | ArcCsch | ArcSec | ArcSech |
    ArcSin | ArcSinh | ArcTan | ArcTanh | Arg | BesselI | BesselJ | BesselK |
    BesselY | Beta | Binomial | Boole | Ceiling | ConditionalExpression |
    Conjugate | Cos | Cosh | CoshIntegral | CosIntegral | Cot | Coth | Csc |
    Csch | CubeRoot | DawsonF | DiscreteDelta | Erf | Erfc | Erfi | Exp |
    ExpIntegralE | ExpIntegralEi | Factorial | Factorial2 | Fibonacci | Floor |
    FractionalPart | FresnelC | FresnelS | Function | Gamma | GammaRegularized |
    GegenbauerC | Gudermannian | HarmonicNumber | Haversine | HermiteH |
    Hypergeometric0F1 | Hypergeometric0F1Regularized | Hypergeometric1F1 |
    Hypergeometric1F1Regularized | Im | IntegerPart | Integrate |
    KroneckerDelta | LambertW | List | Log | Log10 | Log2 | LogGamma |
    LogIntegral | Max | Min | Mod | Norm | Plus | Pochhammer | PolyGamma |
    Power | PrimePi | ProductLog | Quotient | Re | RiemannSiegelTheta |
    RiemannSiegelZ | Round | SawtoothWave | Sec | Sech | Sign | Sin | Sinc |
    Sinh | SinhIntegral | SinIntegral | Sqrt | SquareWave | Surd | Tan | Tanh |
    Times | TriangleWave | UnitStep | WeberE | Zeta;

acceptableHeads@Reals = Union[acceptableHeads@Complexes,
    BarnesG | EllipticE | EllipticK | EllipticNomeQ | InverseEllipticNomeQ |
    InverseErf | InverseErfc | InverseGammaRegularized
];

End[]; Protect@"`*"; EndPackage[];
```

#### Basic Examples

It works with examples from OP:

```
StrictFunctionDomain[(x^2 - x - 2)/(x^2 + x - 6), x]
StrictFunctionDomain[((x - 2) (x + 1))/((x - 2) (x + 3)), x]
(* x < -3 || -3 < x < 2 || x > 2 *)
(* x < -3 || -3 < x < 2 || x > 2 *)
```

In contrast to using simple `FunctionDomain` with held argument, `StrictFunctionDomain` works no matter when singularities appear during evaluation of expression. Singularities can be present in (nested) function definitions:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
f[x_] := 1/x
g[x_, y_] := (x - y)/(x - x y f[x])
```

and they will still be found by `StrictFunctionDomain`, even if function by itself evaluates to singularity free expression:

```
g[x, y] (* 1 *)
StrictFunctionDomain[g[x, y], {x, y}] (* x != 0 && x - y != 0 *)
```

It'll work also for function `Composition` from [previous OP's question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135639/14303):

```
(f@*f)[x] (* x *)
StrictFunctionDomain[(f@*f)[x], x] (* x < 0 || x > 0 *)
```

#### Possible Issues

Using dynamic scoping (`Block`-like constructs) to change behavior of, as fundamental function as, `Power` is not entirely safe. It works as long as `Power` is used only in "mathematical expressions". But if a function uses `Power` in some procedure, not as "symbolic mathematical expressions" that is returned by this function, then changing behavior of `Power` can lead to unexpected behavior of this function.

That's why in above package `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` is used and only behavior of `Power` with non-numeric arguments is changed, which is safer, but still not completely safe.