# Order of evaluation of FunctionDomain, Reduce, Solve, etc

Tags: equation-solving, functions, simplifying-expressions

For the input (mine is much more complicated, this is a toy example):

```
x/x /. x -> 0
```

the output of 1 (as opposed to `Indeterminate`) is understood (although I cannot say I am happy about it), when looking at the `Trace`, which shows that the `x/x` is simplified to `1`, before the `ReplaceAll`.

One way around this problem, is to define the function:

```
f[x_]:=x/x
```

then, `f[0]` indeed produces `Indeterminate`.

However, if I then invoke `FunctionDomain[f[x],x]`, I get `True`.  Apparently `FunctionDomain` also receives a simplified form of the function, prior to calculating the domain.

The workaround for this was suggested to me by @Szabolcs, and originally from @ChipHurst, as can be seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/how-does-functiondomain-work), by wrapping the first argument of `FunctionDomain` in a `Hold`.

However, this continues to bite, when solving equations.  E.g., with the following definition:

```
g[x] := x/Sqrt[x^2]
```

I am okay with:

```
Solve[g[x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

producing `{}`, and:

```
Reduce[g[x] == 0, x]
```

gives me `False`.  But if I give `Reduce` a bit more info, it simplifies `g[x]` to `x`, and for:

```
Reduce[g[x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

I get `x == 0`.

@Szabolcs pointed out that similar results are obtained if the right hand side of the equation is 1, the former form of `Reduce` producing a correct answer, and the latter, an incorrect one.

One possible (ugly) workaround, would be to "remind" `Reduce` of the possible values of `x`:

```
Reduce[g[x] == 0 \[And] FunctionDomain[g[x], x], x, Reals]
```

Producing the correct answer.

However, I'd be most pleased to hear of explanations of this phenomenon, and better solutions.