# Equalities, inequalities and fractions

Tags: inequalities

Today I was surprised by the following treatment of equations in Mathematica. I understand, for example, the following

```
In: a*b/a
Out: b
```

and nobody cares about what was the value of *a*. But I was quite surprised to find out that the same behavior takes place in case of equations. For example,

```
In: a*b/a!=0
Out: b!=0
```

I would expect the result `a!=0&&b!=0` (or the original equation unchanged).

This leads to quite unexpected behavior in more complicated expressions. For example, if I wondered, whether there is a regular matrix of the form $A=\pmatrix{b/a&c\cr 0&a}$ such that $A\pmatrix{0\cr1}=\pmatrix{1\cr 0}$, I would write

```
In: Resolve[Exists[{a,b,c}, {{b/a,c},{0,a}}.{0,1}=={1,0} && Det[{{b/a,c},{0,a}}] != 0]]
Out: True
```

which surprisingly yields positive answer.

So, is this my bad programming? Should I put all equations into Reduce or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [my answer to "How does FunctionDomain work?" question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139329/14303) removable singularities are removed during ordinary evaluation of `Times` and `Power` functions. Since `!=` (`Unequal`) has no evaluation holding `Attributes`, LHS of `a*b/a != 0` expression evaluates to `b` before even `Unequal` "sees" it, so it can do nothing to pick out `a != 0` condition.

Using `RestrictDomain` function from `` Domains` `` package, from already mentioned answer, we can add domain restricting conditions to any expression:

```
a*b/a // RestrictDomain
(* ConditionalExpression[b, a != 0] *)

a*b/a != 0 // RestrictDomain
(* ConditionalExpression[b != 0, a != 0] *)

Det[{{b/a, c}, {0, a}}] != 0 // RestrictDomain
(* ConditionalExpression[b != 0, a != 0] *)
```

Since `Resolve` can't handle `ConditionalExpression`s we need to convert them to logical sentences:

```
condExprToLogicSentence =
    # /. ConditionalExpression[expr_, cond_] :> expr && cond &;

Exists[{a, b, c},
    {{b/a, c}, {0, a}}.{0, 1} == {1, 0} && Det[{{b/a, c}, {0, a}}] != 0 //
    RestrictDomain // condExprToLogicSentence
]
(* Exists[{a, b, c}, {c, a} == {1, 0} && b != 0 && a != 0] *)
% // Resolve
(* False *)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. And `Reduce` should do the thing as well, shouldn't it? A built-in function is more reliable for me then some code I don't understand. On the other hand `Reduce` is probably not very optimal since it is trying to express one variable in terms of the others.