# How to control pre-simplify (Part 1)

Tags: simplifying-expressions

For example, if you enter

```
Reduce [x ^ 2 == x ^ 2 / x, x]
```

The output is

> `x == 0 || x == 1`

Well, the correct answer is `x == 1`. Although this is a trivial example, is there no possibility that similar errors will occur in the process of internal calculation?

Comment: Note that entering `x ^ 2 == x ^ 2 / x` directly automagically performs the cancellation. In any event, read up on the case of ["generically correct"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericSolutions.html) solutions.

Comment: The answer `Reduce` gave you is entirely correct. The quadratic form` x(x - 1)` has roots at 0 and1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's misunderstanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Comment: You could use my [`RestrictDomain`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139329/14303) function: `Reduce[RestrictDomain[x^2 == x^2/x, x, Complexes], x] (* x == 1 *)`.