# The trace on my plot goes beyond the domain of the function plotted

Tags: plotting, functions

Here's the domain of the function:

[image]

When I'm trying to plot it Mathematica just shows a graph of $x+1$.

[image]

Here's what happens if we put $x$ in formula from outside of a function's domain:

[image]

I'm not sure whether it's a bug or Mathematica simplifies the equation to $x+1$ but I'm searching for a way to plot it correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If I just input `x^Log[x, x + 1]` _Mathematica_ returns `1 + x`. So I think it's a simplification thing. You could use `Plot[x^Log[x, x + 1], {x, -5, 5}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x}, 0 < x < 1 || x > 1]]` to get it plotting over the domain you want.

Comment: Even without simplification mathematica gladly works in the complex domain, `Log[-5, -4] // N -> 0.971177 + 0.0562626 I ` then `(-5)^(0.971177 + 0.0562626 I) -> -4+eps I`

Comment: You can tell MA that `Log`should be real: `Plot[x^Re[Log[x, x + 1]], {x, -5, 5}]`, although it is not quite the same.

Comment: I claim that MA correctly plots this function, because the `FunctionDomain` is the whole real axis. Maybe you are concerned that intermediate steps are only possible in your domain. However, this is not right mathematical logic: have a look at $sin(x)=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2i$---the result is real although each exponent is complex for each real $x$.

Comment: Evaluation of `x^Log[x, x + 1]` expression to `1 + x` is ["generically correct"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html) for `Power` and `Log` as functions of complex arguments, which is how they are defined in *Mathematica*. You could use my [`RestrictDomain`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139329/14303) function: `RestrictDomain[x^Log[x, x + 1], x, Reals]` to get expression with domain restriction, assuming all functions are restricted to `Reals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming e.g. a real functions realm one could expect what you expect. But there is no straightforward way to do so and in expressions + complexes world it is correct.

The problem is that there is no `FunctionFormula` expression with special rules in Mathematica so your example will be simplified automatically.

Fortunately `FunctionDomain` handles uneavaluated formula well:

```
FunctionDomain[Unevaluated[x^Log[x, x + 1]], x]
```

> ```
> 0 < x < 1 || x > 1
> ```

```
Plot[
  x^Log[x, x + 1]
, {x, -10, 10}
, RegionFunction -> Function[
    x
  , Evaluate@FunctionDomain[Unevaluated[x^Log[x, x + 1]], x]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[f]

f[x_] := x^Log[x, x + 1] /; 0 < x < 1 || x > 1;

f /@ {-5, 0, 1, 5}

(* {f[-5], f[0], f[1], 6} *)

Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]